# Is this a valid group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I take $\alpha = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$ (the third root of unity) and $\beta = \sqrt{2}$, and the generated set

$$\langle \alpha, \beta | \alpha^3 = e, \beta^2 =e \rangle$$

with the operation being the usual product in the complex numbers. Is this a valid group? I mean, it is closed, associative, has an identity element ($e = 1$) and each element has an inverse (if the element is $\alpha^k\beta^j$, then its inverse is $\alpha^{3-k}\beta^{2-j}$), so it is a group, right? Or did I get one of those wrong?

And if it is a group, would it be correct to say that the only automorphism is the identity mapping? My reasoning being that we must have $\phi(e) = e$, and if we were to have $\phi(\beta) = \beta^k\alpha^j, k=0,1, j =1,2$, then $\phi(\beta^2) = \phi(e) = e \neq \phi(\beta)\phi(\beta) = \beta^{0}\alpha^m, m=1,2$, a contradiction.

I appreciate any corrections! Thanks.

Edits: If the first few comments don't seem to make sense, it's because I had a few things wrong in the original question.

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha = -1$? Because as you've written it, $\alpha^2 = 2$. The presentation you give is valid, it just doesn't correspond to the value of $\alpha$ you gave.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your definition. Would you say that $2\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^3 = 1$?

Comment: Like the other commenters, I'm not totally sure what you mean here... if you're taking the product inside of the complex numbers, then it is not true that $\alpha^3 = \beta^2 = e = 1$. It seems like what you're trying to do is take the quotient of the free abelian (abelian because you originally wanted to use multiplication in $\Bbb C$) group on two generators $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ by the subgroup generated by $(3,0)$ and $(0,2)$.

Comment: @T.Gunn I had mixed up $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I apologize. I edited the question, but I meant that $\alpha$ be third root of unity and $\beta$ be the square root.

Comment: Your edit does not fix the problem: $\sqrt{2}^n = 1$ if and only if $n = 0$. The primitive square root of unity is $-1$, not $\sqrt{2}$, as @T.Gunn said.

Comment: @TobErnack I had switched $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I think Stahl's comment means I can't do it either way.

Comment: @Stahl I thought I could do something akin to "integers mod n", where I take $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2$ and make it be $1$, but from your answer I'm guessing I cannot do that, correct? Thanks!

Comment: @Stahl also, yes, I forgot to fix the placement of the phrase "square root of unit", will re-edit

Comment: What you want is essentially what I wrote in my other comment. You begin with the subgroup of $\Bbb C^\times$ generated by $\zeta_3$ and $\sqrt{2}$ (which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(3)\times\Bbb Z$ via $\zeta_3^a\sqrt{2}^b\mapsto(a + 3\Bbb Z,b)$), and then quotient out by the subgroup generated by $2$ (which under my isomorphism becomes $\{0\}\times 2\Bbb Z$). So, the group you want to look at is $\langle\zeta_3,\sqrt{2}\rangle/\langle 2\rangle$ (which is no longer naturally a subgroup of $\Bbb C^\times$!!), and saying you want to set $2 = 1$ inside $\Bbb C^\times$ is confusing/imprecise.

Comment: If you want to say that there exists a $\beta$ such that $\beta^2 = 1$ or $\beta^2 = e$ say that, and you would have a group.  But when you say $\beta = \sqrt 2$ then you are suggesting something else.  We could say that $\beta = -1$ and then between $\alpha, \beta, e$ we would generate a cyclic group of order $6.$

Comment: Um, what's a generated set if alpha and beta are fixed and defined?  In your generated set notation maybe you shouldn't use e for both euler's nummber and (I presume the group identity) as $\beta^2 = 2$ this really doesn't match the generated set.

Comment: @Stahl Very enlightening comments, thank you very much! Can I ask you to post them in "answer" form so I can accept it?

Comment: @mlaci Sure, I'll write something up along the lines of what I've outlined here.

Comment: @DougM I think I understand what you're saying, and I really don't know anything about algebra, but would the same presentation give the same group regardless of what I defined by $\beta$ and as a product?

Comment: @fleablood I apologize for any mistakes, as I'm new to algebra. Are you saying $\alpha$ and $\beta$ cannot be fixed and/or defined? And as for the use of $e$, I really hadn't caught on to that, so thank you.

Comment: No. I'm saying I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I'm gathering that I did a lot wrong with that question. Thank you.

Comment: @DougM Ah, nevermind, I see the source of my confusion: I thought the group I was trying to describe wouldn't be a cyclic group, which I now see is clearly wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the group generated by $e^{2\pi i/3} =: \zeta_3$ and $\sqrt{2}$ with group operation given by multiplication of complex numbers. One might write this group as $G = \langle \zeta_3,\sqrt{2}\rangle\subseteq\Bbb C^\times$. Because $\Bbb C^\times$ (and hence our group $G$) already has a group operation defined on it, we cannot demand that $\sqrt{2}^2 = 1$ without leaving the group we live in, because $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2\neq 1$ inside of $\Bbb C^\times$.

However, group theory gives us a way to start with a group $G$ and then create a new group $G'$ from $G$ such that the desired relationship holds: this is the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) construction. In this case, you want the relationship $\sqrt{2}^2 = 1$ to hold (which, as we've noted, does not hold in $\Bbb C$, and hence does not hold in $G$). So what we do is form the quotient of $G$ by the subgroup generated by $2$ inside of $G$. This gives us a new group
$$
G' := G/\langle 2\rangle = \{\zeta_3^a\sqrt{2}^b\langle 2\rangle\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\},
$$
whose elements are cosets $g\langle 2\rangle = \{g x\mid x\in\langle 2\rangle\} = \{g 2^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$, where $g\in G$. In $G'$, multiplication is performed in the following way: $g\langle 2\rangle\cdot h\langle 2\rangle := gh\langle 2\rangle$ (one must check that this is well-defined, or independent of the choice of representatives $g$ and $h$ used to represent the cosets), and $g\langle 2\rangle$ is the identity of $G'$ if and only if $g\in \langle 2\rangle$.

The quotient group $G'$ admits a natural map from $G$ given by
\begin{align*}
G&\to G'\\
g&\mapsto g\langle 2\rangle
\end{align*}
which is surjective with kernel precisely $\langle 2\rangle$. Note that however, $G'$ is *not* naturally a subgroup of $G$ or even $\Bbb C$: subgroups map *into* the given group $G$, but this has a map from our given group $G$ to it.

In general, one can create a group generated by any set $S = \{s_\alpha\mid\alpha\in A\}$ (called generators) subject to the restriction that certain identities $R$ hold within the group. To do this, we begin with the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) $F_S$ on our set of generators $S$, which is the group whose elements are formal strings
$$
s_{\alpha_1}^{n_{\alpha_1}}s_{\alpha_2}^{n_{\alpha_2}}\cdots s_{\alpha_r}^{n_{\alpha_r}},
$$
where each $\alpha_i\in A$, and each $n_{\alpha_i}\in\Bbb Z$, and whose group operation concatenation of strings (just smash them together). Within this group, you may only make simplifications of the form $s_x^{n}\cdot s_x^{-n} = e$. The group has no relationships between the various $s_\alpha$'s. But we may now demand that relationships hold between the $s_\alpha$'s similar to the way we did with $G$: we write our relations in the form $s_{\alpha_1}^{n_{\alpha_1}}s_{\alpha_2}^{n_{\alpha_2}}\cdots s_{\alpha_r}^{n_{\alpha_r}} = e$ (above, you had $\sqrt{2}^2 = 1$), and then we form the quotient group $F/R$ of $F$ by $R$, where $R$ is the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by the relations: i.e., the normal subgroup generated by all the $s_{\alpha_1}^{n_{\alpha_1}}s_{\alpha_2}^{n_{\alpha_2}}\cdots s_{\alpha_r}^{n_{\alpha_r}}$'s that we wanted to be equal to the identity. This group will be the group with the least amount of relationships possible between the elements of $s$, subject to the condition that all of your demanded relationships hold.

We can construct your group $G'$ completely abstractly in this way: we want a group generated by 2 elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$, subject to the conditions that

1. multiplication is commutative,
2. $\alpha^3 = e$, and
3. $\beta^2 = e$.

Condition 1 could be expressed as a relation (how?), but we may also simply use it to simplify our problem: we do not need to take the usual free group on two generators $F_2$, but instead, we can start with the free abelian group on two generators $\Bbb Z\alpha\oplus\Bbb Z\beta$, which is much simpler (in particular, every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, so we don't need to worry about that particular point). Now, we want to take the quotient of $\Bbb Z\alpha\oplus\Bbb Z\beta$ by the subgroup generated by $(3\alpha,0)$ and $(0,2\beta)$ (I'm now writing this group additively). This subgroup is simply $3\Bbb Z\alpha\oplus2\Bbb Z\beta$, and when we form the quotient group, we get
$$
(\Bbb Z\alpha\oplus\Bbb Z\beta)/(3\Bbb Z\alpha\oplus2\Bbb Z\beta)\cong (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z,
$$
which you can check is isomorphic to the group $G'$.

Comment: Very educational, thank you! I think I've learned a lot from this. (Also, I don't know if I'm supposed to answer the "How?", but I'm  thinking with $ab=ba$ or even $b^{-1}aba^{-1}=e$)

Comment: @mlaci You're welcome; I'm glad it helped!

Comment: @mlaci You didn't have to answer the "how," it was just for you to think about if you didn't see it immediately, but the second thing you've written is the right relation. In general, to demand multiplication is commutative in a free group generated by a set $S$, you need to quotient by the normal subgroup generated by the set of all possible $sts^{-1}t^{-1}$, where $s,t\in S$.